# Jquery sortable stange mouse offset

Tags: jquery, mouse, jquery-ui-sortable, offset

I'm working with the jQuery sortable plugin( 2 connected lists) and have a strange bug. When you drag the picture the mouse is above the dragged item

screenshot: http://img408.imageshack.us/i/mouseb.png/

Html for one of the lists

```
    <ul class="flickr_key_ul ui-sortable">       
            <li><img style="display: inline;" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/1039/548804108_a8816f42f5_s.jpg" alt="Up the Ginnel" title="Up the Ginnel" class="flickr_image"></li>
            <li><img style="display: inline;" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/1116/548804090_7e625a461b_s.jpg" alt="Down the Ginnel" title="Down the Ginnel" class="flickr_image"></li>
            <li><img style="display: inline;" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/1011/548804074_75f2c0bd0e_s.jpg" alt="Entering the Ginnel" title="Entering the Ginnel" class="flickr_image"></li>
            <li><img style="display: inline;" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/1345/548804064_6023b070a7_s.jpg" alt="Up Bachelor Lane" title="Up Bachelor Lane" class="flickr_image"></li>

            <li><img style="display: inline;" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/1183/548804020_3116d900ce_s.jpg" alt="Down Bachelor Lane" title="Down Bachelor Lane" class="flickr_image"></li>
            <li><img style="display: none;" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/1325/548771897_0a32a6492a_s.jpg" alt="Flower" title="Flower" class="flickr_image"></li>
            <li><img style="display: none;" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/1411/548771891_e37de6bcc0_s.jpg" alt="Steps" title="Steps" class="flickr_image"></li>
            <li><img style="display: none;" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/1424/548771883_23a4909300_s.jpg" alt="Hopwood Bridle Way" title="Hopwood Bridle Way" class="flickr_image"></li>
            <li><img style="display: none;" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/1350/548771867_beaf20476b_s.jpg" alt="Cat, Sleeping" title="Cat, Sleeping" class="flickr_image"></li>
            <li><img style="display: none;" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/1393/548771853_af19a5dac2_s.jpg" alt="Road Cones, Hiding" title="Road Cones, Hiding" class="flickr_image"></li>
    </ul>
```

sortable configuration:

```
 horizontal: {
            helper: "clone", // Instead of dragging the real image a copy will be dragged
            connectWith: ["#flickr_sidebar ul"], // To be able to drag and drop an image to another image gallery they need to be connected
            cursor: 'pointer', //change the cursor when dragging
            appendTo: 'body', //When dropped the images need to be appended to the image gallery where they are dropped
            containment: rootel, //Make sure the user can't drag the images outside the widget
            revert: true, // if the user releases the image ouside the dropbox it'll return to it's original position
            zIndex: 9999
        },
```

Anyone know how to get the mouse in the middle or something ? (cursorAt doesn't work)

Comment: i have similar problem, but the draggable item is on top offset of the mouse.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

i had the same problem with mouse pointer offset when changed left alignment from {float:left} to {display:inline}. the solution is:

```
cursorAt: { top: 0, left: 0 }
```

this works for both sortable and draggable:

```
$( "#someid" ).draggable({cursorAt: { top: 0, left: 0 },...})
$( "#someid" ).sortable({cursorAt: { top: 0, left: 0 },...})
```

Comment: Just wanted to thank you! I ran into this issue and your fix worked like a charm!

Comment: This is working for the *first* drag for me, then after that, I get the weird offset again. Any suggestions?

Comment: The container of the sortable has to have position:relative. That fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
horizontal: {
        helper: "clone", // Instead of dragging the real image a copy will be dragged
        connectWith: ["#flickr_sidebar ul"], // To be able to drag and drop an image to another image gallery they need to be connected
        cursor: 'pointer', //change the cursor when dragging
        cursorAt: { cursor: "move", top: 6, left: 275 },
        appendTo: 'body', //When dropped the images need to be appended to the image gallery where they are dropped
        containment: rootel, //Make sure the user can't drag the images outside the widget
        revert: true, // if the user releases the image ouside the dropbox it'll return to it's original position
        zIndex: 9999
    },
```

Comment: Had a similar problem. The appendTo: 'body' resolved it.